# How to apply strike-through using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

My problem is that when I apply the strike-through or double strike-through formatting and save the file it is not reflected in output file.

Following code does not do the trick:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Strike through the following text').strike = True
document.save('demo.docx')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
p.add_run('Strike through the following text').font.strike = True
```

`strike` is a property of the `font` object : [docs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/font.html?highlight=strike)

**EDIT**

If multiple font properties were to be changed the code should be :

```
sentence = p.add_run('Strike through the following text')
sentence.font.strike = True
sentence.font.name = 'Comic Sans MS'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! what if I needed to give the same text another property too. Eg: ``p.add_run(x).font.name = 'Comic Sans MS'`` as well as ``strike``