# How can I detect strikethrough text from .docx tables?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm using python-docx to parse some tables to dictionaries. However, some of those tables contain strikethrough text. This text needs to be excluded.

I have already found [how to detect strike-through through text in paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904470/checking-for-particular-style-using-python-docx/27910938#27910938) or [how to apply strike-through text myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269615/how-to-apply-strike-through-using-python-docx), but nowhere can I find how to check for strikethrough text in tables. As far as I can tell from the documentation, neither the Table object nor the cells have a "Run" object, which is something that Paragraphs have that contain style data.

Without the Run object, there isn't any style data.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that I totally missed something crucial in the documentation of this library.

Apparently, cells not only have a `text` attribute, but **also** a `paragraphs` attribute, which in turn has `Run` objects.

See [the section of the docs on tables](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html#docx.table._Cell).

Knowing this, we can get formatting in table cells as follows:

```
table.cell(0,1).paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.strike
```

So, it turns out the method is not different from paragraphs after all.